# Insufficient privileges in networkmanager even though polkit policy set

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

When running as a normal user nm-applet doesn't allow me to select a wireless network saying "insufficient privileges". But I've edited the polkot policy file

/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy

to have <allow_any>yes</allow_any> for everything. To be extra sure I also have <allow_active>yes</allow_active> and <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive> as well.

All of this is on Fedora 17 (polkit-0.104, NetworkManager-0.9.4) without running gnome3, only gnome-settings-daemon.

polkitd, dbus-daemon and dbus-launch are all running. 
What can be the reason?

Comment: Which distro? Or at least give us which version of polkit and networkmanager you're running. They've changed a lot since their inception.

Comment: Added version info: fedora 17

Comment: Turns out the solution is here:

http://blog.falconindy.com/articles/back-to-basics-with-x-and-systemd.html

Manually starting X by startx and polkit are not cool together :) But you say "startx -- vt01" then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the [link](http://blog.falconindy.com/articles/back-to-basics-with-x-and-systemd.html), listed in a comment by the OP:

> Turns out the solution is here: blog.falconindy.com/articles/… Manually starting X by startx and polkit are not cool together :) But you say "startx -- vt01" then everything will be fine. –  Daniel Oct 19 '12 at 15:54

A number of issues may arise with authenticated sessions when the user starts the `X` server from the console with `startx` without any parameters; apparently, a new terminal is launched with the Xserver session, where the established authentication from within the console session is not "transferred" to the newly-created X-session.
As a result of this "loss of authentication", the unprivileged user is not allowed to "speak to privileged processes" and/or ask for authentication.

The suggested workaround is to start the `X` server from the console with the current VT number passed as a parameter, e.g.:

```
xinit -- vt01
```

This will cause `xinit` to start the `X` server within the same terminal (with the authenticated session), instead of launching a new TTY.

Similarly, according to a comment to that [referenced article](http://blog.falconindy.com/articles/back-to-basics-with-x-and-systemd.html), `systemd-logind` puts the appropriate vt in the environment variable `$XDG_VTNR`; so, one might create a short script or `alias` to facilitate the correct xinit process by including

```
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp vt$XDG_VTNR "$@"
```

**Note**
Arch-linux's version of `xorg-xinit` includes this line by default as of `xorg-xinit-1.3.2-3`, according to the blog-post on [blog.falconindy.com](http://blog.falconindy.com/articles/back-to-basics-with-x-and-systemd.html)